# Time not entered in mysql ? Java

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a datetime field in mysql table and i am using JPA for persisting data but only date goes in database. Time always shows 00:00:00. What should i do?

I am not doing any manipulation with Date. All i do is to assign `new Date()` to a variable and store it in database.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the annotation `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`

Answer (score 1):

Example below:

```
private String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

Tips like these can be found on http://www.java-tips.org

Comment: Hi VoodooChild, even new Date() by default has time. So there is no need to set the time explicitly. Actually, chris_i is right i had temporaltype.date. Changed it to timestamp and now everything works fine.